# Raspberry PI keeps on rebooting

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, boot, noobs

I am a new Raspberry Pi user. I bought a Pi 3 recently. I installed Rasbian on it by using NOOBS and SD Card Formatter. After completing the installation i set a root password by using `sudo passwd`.

The problem is, after the installation, I tried to open the inbuilt web browser. After it opened, I tried to open a website but as soon as I did, it started rebooting continuously. After rebooting automatically for 4-5 times it finally shows the desktop. Again, I tried to open the browser and then a website, and the whole process repeated again.

Also, when I switch on the pi after auto rebooting for 3-4 times it starts and gives the desktop screen.

I checked the space on my SD card by using `free -m`, and the output said I had 650 MB space left, even though I am using a 16 GB memory card.

Comment: What power supply are you using?

Comment: @An Epic Person 110-240V AC 50-60Hz

Comment: @An Epic Person It came with the kit

Comment: How many amps? Is this the input voltage?

Comment: @An Epic Person 2Amp

Comment: @An Epic Person Yes this is the input voltage

Comment: @An Epic Person It looks like i was having a faulty adapter to provide power to the PI. I replaced it and now the PI is working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it surely is a power supply problem.
The allowed voltage range is the normal one (for 5V logic) 5.0V ±5%
so its a the range between 4.75V and 5.25V.
Note that the lower limit of 4.75V is more a matter of many USB devices not working below that value than it is that the PI itself is that sensitive, especially as much of it (including the ethernet/hub chip, and the SD-card) is working from 3,3V through a regulator on board of the PI that will keep working even with say 4.0V.

Also note that many 5V logic devices will be damaged by voltages of 6.5V or higher! Therefore there is a protection device on the PI (D17) that will short the 5V supply if about 6.0V is supplied! Then the (poly)fuse will blow out to protect D17 from burning up! If you do not power the PI through the normal micro-USB port then you are actually bypassing that fuse!

there is a section of the PI Wiki at http://elinux.org/RaspberryPiBoard dedicated to boot problems like this.

Comment: `free -m` outputs the memory, not free space on disk.

Answer (score 1):

I put a small fan over it and that apparently fixed it. The voltage issue was confusing because it was in tolerance but maybe it was just too hot.